# How to forward fill values of user balances to get the sum of total balance per day for all users in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have usersbalance table in Big Query that stores the data for user balance per day but the records only get added to the table for the user if he did any transaction. If a user didn't make any transaction on a day, then no records get added.
I am struggling to figure out how I can forward fill user balance from the first day when they made a transaction until the day when their balance changes again to do the SUM and GROUP BY balance_day.

User balances table:

| UserID | balance_day | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-02-01 | 5.65 |
| 123 | 2023-02-14 | 7.45 |
| 123 | 2023-03-27 | 10.05 |
| 456 | 2023-02-13 | 3.54 |
| 456 | 2023-02-27 | 7.89 |
| 456 | 2023-03-11 | 3.45 |

I am looking to find total balance for all users per day and looking to get below output:

2023-02-01 5.65

2023-02-02 5.65

.

.

2023-02-13 9.19

2023-02-14 16.64

and so on.

Thank you in advance for any tip/guidance :)

So my logic is:

- usd_value_balances_per_day CTE - take balance for each user per day
- all_users CTE - first day when user made a transaction and had a balance (first record for a user in user balances table)
- all_dates CTE - I want to get total balance per day from 11/08/2022 onwards so generating all the dates. Here is where the error is I think as I am duplicating dates by joining with all_users.
- results - forward filling user balances from the first day

```
WITH usd_value_balances_per_day AS(
SELECT
user_id,
balance
balance_day
FROM
userbalances
),

all_users AS(
select min(balance_day) as min_date, user_id
from usd_value_balances_per_day
group by user_id
),


all_dates AS(
select *
from all_users, unnest(generate_date_array('2022-08-11', current_date())) as balance_day
where balance_day >= min_date
),


results AS(
select balance_day, user_id, LAST_VALUE(balance IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY balance_day
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS balance
from all_dates
left join usd_value_balances_per_day using (user_id, balance_day)
order by balance_day
)

select balance_day, SUM(balance) as total_balance
from results
group by balance_day
order by balance_day
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
WITH days AS (
  SELECT balance_day
  FROM (
    SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(MIN(balance_day), MAX(balance_day)) days
    FROM your_table
  ), UNNEST(days) balance_day
)
SELECT balance_day, ROUND(SUM(SUM(balance)) OVER(ORDER BY balance_day), 2) balance
FROM days
LEFT JOIN your_table
USING(balance_day)
GROUP BY balance_day
ORDER BY balance_day
```

if apply to sample data as in your question

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 123 UserID, DATE '2023-02-01' balance_day, 5.65 balance UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '2023-02-14', 7.45 UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '2023-03-27', 10.05 UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, '2023-02-13', 3.54 UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, '2023-02-27', 7.89 UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, '2023-03-11', 3.45 
),
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! The query works perfectly! The only problem is that it stops forward fill user balance when a user makes the last transaction. E.g. if user made a last transaction on 2023-03-03 and has a balance 1.54 it doesn't forward fill till today's date even if a user still has a balance and still should be included in calculations for total balance.

User_id              Balance
2023-03-02       1.54
2023-03-03       1.54
And then it stops

It doesn't forward fill for non-existing dates for that user. I've changed MAX(balance) to CURRENT_DATE but that didn't fix it

Comment: that was not part of your question - right?. meantime check out  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682181/5221944 - it addresses that use case